# orientdb- ETL import vs java custom import with embedded db

Tags: java, orientdb, etl

I am prototyping a data mining tool to harvest data from multiple sources

1) MySQL db
     - 2,000,000 vertices    20,000,000 edges
2) custom data files-
     - 2,000,000 vertices   700,000,000 edges
3) different custom data files
      - 300000 vertices   500,000,000 edges

From a performance standpoint, is it better to use ETL or custom Java loaders with embedded db?

It is easy to transform the data from the custom data files to CSV or JSON

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm the ETL maintainer, other than input data format I would take care on which kind of transformation your data sets need AND how many times you need to move data.

ETL is configurable to do some transformations, and you can use it with a plocal db to achieve maximun performance. If you need to reimport frequently, or very complex transoformations, or if your data format can vary time to time, you can write a custom java program.